# How and why is Subaru connected to the Witch (Satella)?

Tags: re-zero

All throughout the series, specifically, within the second Arc of the story, there are references to Subaru smelling like the **Witch's Scent**, Giving us the knowledge that he is Definitely connected to her.

Why is this? It's well known that Subaru was pulled from modern day Japan into this Fantasy world, as well as that he has the ability **"Return to Death"** In which he has the ability to *Respawn*.

These things most likely have things in common with his relations to the witch, though... What exactly is the relationship? How are they connected?

Comment: This has not been made clean in anime yet, and to get more information you would probably have to read manga. But then it would spoil you the anime adaptation.

Comment: The Manga is, As far as i'm aware, still only in the second Arc (The Mansion Arc), I asked for an answer, knowing full well it would spoil stuff. Whether or not it's mentioned or not within the anime's span isn't known, so I can't comment there really.

But yeah. Spoilers are fine. As long as they answer my question.

Comment: There is a light novel of RE:Zero out there, 8 volumes according to WIKI, so i would assume that we have something there, but I have yet to read it. Normally, we only get 1-2 volumes per season of anime or so.

Comment: to dump all i know, the manga had 3 adaptation, each for respective arc. They are Daisshou - Outo no Ichinichi Hen, Dainishou - Yashiki no Shuukan Hen, and Daisanshou - Truth of Zero. The second and third arc manga are released simultanousely. If you're willing for spoilers i suggest get the novels (or get some spoilers on online forums). Although i believe, the novel yet to explain things explicitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Satella The Jealous Witch is in love with Subaru. Why though is not known to the current arc of the latest source arc 6 (web) may change in the official version (Published book).

The first time we supposed to see her was supposed to be in the current anime arc which is arc 3 it is not shown during the anime but every time Subaru dies he is transported (symbolizes by the arm grabbing him) to a new timeline while that happen he is transported first to a void places (for depiction look at opening 1 where the places is covered with smokes symbolizing the witches miasma which may explain why the smell grew thicker everytime he re-spawn).

He saw an image of a girl which became clearer every loop. not only thus images pop up the more significant changes that you would observe in the anime (if they didn't cut it) he will hear the whisper of Satella saying 'I Love You' in every attempt of a reveal.(**episode 20**)

The fact that he say 'I love Emilia' during the Rem scene will put on perspective why Emilia was killed during his attempt to reveal the power

Comment: This explains a lot. Thankyou. I have another question, in response. The strength of the Miasma increasing, is this due to his timeline getting closer to hers? Assuming every timeline is set, it wouldn't be too far a stretch to say she's pulling him closer to her, would it?

Comment: In theory (im not sure since i basing it in the OP and from what i observe in the series) whenever he arrived at the void the miasma attach itself to his soul/conciousness/memory like when dipping a white towel inside a water full of murky water it will get darker and darker everytime.

Answer (score -1):

Emilia was the Witch when she was younger. Emilia slowly becomes the witch who at some point goes back in time and "fucks everything up" which is why people think the current Emilia is related to the witch which she actually is. Older Subaru is basically the mental essence of all the finger, he went crazy in the future.

It all comes down to one of those complicated time things, like what came first the chicken or the egg. Subaru got pulled back in time, where he met Emilia, who became the witch and he became the finger which led to Subaru being pulled into the past in the first place.

Comment: Is this supposition, or does it have sources? If the latter, you might want to include the source of your answer somewhere in it.

Comment: Pretty good theory.  I'm guessing by the downvotes it's not cannon, but it wraps up things nicely.

Answer (score -5):

This isnt a fact but a theory but I am starting to learn towards the idea that Emilia is Satella. Subaru is the flugel. Hence the flugel tree and why he planted it. I think Emilia will take the witch genes from Subaru possibly to save him from the insanity? Maybe all 7 witch genes was too much. This also may be why Satella says he loves Subaru. I think that guy might be right about the time travel. Satella said something about Subaru showing him the world,kissing her etc. Anyways yea. Subaru and Emilia somehow travelled back to the past which may be the authority of envy- Time? This also explains why Echidna hates Emilia. Echidna hates Satella. So much deetailsss gah. Anyways we'll know soon enough. Lets be patient :) if Im right. Subaru is in for some deep shit. Is he gonna kill Emilia this time to free her or is he gonna seal her again? Will he save her this time?