# What does Satella whisper to Subaru as he spams declarations of his return by death?

Tags: re-zero

The answer here [How and why is Subaru connected to the Witch (Satella)?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/34366/how-and-why-is-subaru-connected-to-the-witch-satella) hints that it might be "I love you", and that communication with Satella becomes clearer the more Subaru dies (and more loops trigger, bringing his timeline/world closer to Satella's). [Citation needed]

What does Satella tell Subaru as he spams declarations of his ability? I was wondering if she generally says the same thing each time (so removing the case when Subaru took Betelgeuse along for the ride), if it was intentionally muted in the anime in previous instances. Does the LN/WN have her silently whisper?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She says "I love you".

[Source from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Re_Zero/comments/4xvnz9/what_did_satella_whisper_to_subaru/)

> From what's been hinted at in the web novels I think she whispered "I love you"

A commenter named "Mitrospeed" on a certain anime site who has a great knowledge of both Light and Web Novel also said the following in his review to episode 20:

> Subaru makes use of the one thing that makes him somewhat useful which is his role as a bait. He tries to spread the witch’s miasma and attract the whale with it. But for the first time we see a difference. Behind him we can see a shadowy figure which clearly seems to be Satella. You can lipread what she says; it’s "I love you".

I cannot confirm that it really lipreads to "I love you", but I see no reason to distrust the commenter.